# Why can't travis-ci find a library that it seemed to install happily

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have a small python web-scraper that depends upon BeautifSoup https://github.com/fgregg/legistar-scrape. My tests run happily locally, but on travis-ci, nosetests immediately errors out because it can't find BeautifulSoup, which it looks like it just finished installing.

Travis-CI Build log here: https://travis-ci.org/fgregg/legistar-scrape/jobs/5628189

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recommendation

[Change this](https://github.com/fgregg/legistar-scrape/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
install: "sudo pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

to this:

```
install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

Check [here](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/python/) for usage.

## Proof of concept

I forked your github project, added my fork to my travis-ci account, made the change I suggested, committed, and pushed to github. Here are two successful travis-ci builds: [python 2.6](https://travis-ci.org/hughdbrown/legistar-scrape/jobs/5633239) and [python 2.7](https://travis-ci.org/hughdbrown/legistar-scrape/jobs/5633240).

## Virtualenvs

Are you using a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for your python development? Or are you using `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` when you run locally? I'd recommend you look into virtualenvs and stop using `sudo pip install`. That's what most python developers do these days. And that's how travis-ci works: it creates a virtualenv and runs your app from that.

## Nosetests

Separately, your nosetests are really slow because you are integration testing -- you are hitting live servers across the internet, right? Look up how to use the [mock library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) so that you mock the HTML returned from your URLs instead of actually hitting those servers.